Noise simulation (LTSpice) of gyrator with ADA4523-1
I've been having trouble with my impedance multiplier simulation lately. Specifically, it is an impedance multiplier. I'm trying to simulate this circuit's noise when multiplying a capacitor's impedance.
The problem is that only the simulation's first iteration gives me a worthwhile result, while other iterations are several orders of magnitude smaller.



As you can see from the pictures, the other iterations are smaller by several orders of magnitude.
One problem could be that LTSpice does not have a noise model for ADA4523-1. However, even if I set the resistor to "noiseless", the results are still the same.
